# Is it a good strategy to add a lot of filtered indexes?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing, filtered-index

I have the following situation:

There is a service that any given time can call the same SP in parallel 1 up to 40 - 50 times in the same time.

When called ones the SP performs fine (800ms to 1s).
As the number of calls grow the times grow.
The stored procedure runs on 4 tables with a tree like structure, the first one having close to 1 million records while tier 4 tables are close to 90 million. 
Each call of SP runs on an entity and is completely isolated by the others that are called in the same time, as calls for the same entity are sequential.
The reason for performance degradation is mostly due to IO and concurrency (locking and stuff) and not processor.
At one point in time I can have 1 up to 2-300 entities for which the SP is called.(active entities)
The queries use 3-4 indexes (on these big tables).
The life of an entity is somewhere between 1 hour and 3-4 hours.

What I want to do is that when a new entity appears to create a series of filtered indexes for that particular entity and force SQL to use them in order to minimize IO. When the entity is drop to also drop the indexes.

This being a lot of work I thought to first ask here if it is worth it. My problem is that I do not know how the filtered indexes are updated. The thing is that I will have let's say 600 indexes (200 entities x 3 indexes). One entity will be updated at around 10 seconds mark. I do not know what stress will the updating of this indexes put on the system. I do not want to trade insert speed for select speed. I am guessing that sql is smart enough so that if an entity is updated only it's indexes will get updated. The indexes will be fairly small and fast updatable but to check 600 indexes for the filter condition must consume some resource.

Comment: Why create extra indexes for each entity? Can't you just have a few with `EntityID` as the leading column? That will allow SQL Server to restrict its accesses to the index range that entity is in.

Comment: This is how it is now. But as I said I have a lot of parallel processes running around on the same index. The IO of the huge number of rows is high enough on a single process, when I have multiple processes I have issues with locks on those indexes. The code is good enough not to produce deadlocks, but the locks are still making it slower.

Comment: Then consider doing something against that locking. Use snapshot isolation. You said that the processes act on distinct set of rows so there won't be conflicts. Btw, SQL Server supports about 250 indexes per table max.

Comment: How have you verified you are having IO and blocking?  If the indexing is good and the concurrency level is set right, I wouldn't think these would be a big issue.

Comment: @usr I didn't try with snapshop isolation, I will try to see how it goes. Also I didn't know about the 250 indexes limit. On a simple google it is not.

Comment: @Dave I verified yes. The SP has a high IO count and when the server goes under pressure I have IO_COMPLETION as last wait type for a lot of processes and also the SPs wait one for another

Comment: @usr for MSSQL 2008 the maximum number of indexes is 1000 (1 clustered and 999 nc)

Comment: Have you tuned the query as best as possible?  When you look at the execution plan, where are the most reads occurring?

Comment: By my experience, I think I exhausted all tuning possibilities. It's not a single point, the SP is long and complex. It uses a lot of data, CLR that reads from that data and sends new values and so on. There is no read without indexes. It's a normal thing to happen. That's why I am asking this question, though this endeavor will not be easy at all. But I could not find anywhere information on a basic level for filtered indexes and performance impact.

Comment: By splitting the data into many indexes you will not reduce the working set of data. You will have the same amount of IO.; Note also, that a predicate like `col = @col` cannot be satisfied from a filtered index in general even if @col happens to be a value matching the index filter.; I haven't seen evidence of blocking yet. Can you provide some?

Comment: You are wrong, here .. The IO would be significantly smaller as the index will be around 100k to 500k times smaller. Also I think to force SQL to use the index (without even having a where clause). Of the blocking, the reason I am saying of it is that when I run sp_who2 or similar SPs I have processes waiting one for another.

Comment: You cannot force SQL Server to use a filtered index if that would result in a semantic change. You must have a matching predicate that is statically discoverable.; I don't see why IO would be less because even with a full unfiltered index SQL Server only uses and loads the parts that are being queried. 99% of the index can be cold and never used. Regarding blocking: Yes, that is good evidence of blocking. I'd remove that first. Who knows, maybe 99% of the time is spent blocking and you have an easy solution.

Comment: If the I/O is happening because you are reading a bunch of data through CLR and have complicated stored procedures with lots of statements, why do you think filtered indexes will magically compensate for that?

Comment: @DumitrescuBogdan .. You mentioned you use sp_who2 to find blocking but wondered if you used DMV's (sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats, sys.dm_exec_query_stats, sys.dm_exec_query_plan, sys.dm_exec_query_text) to get more info on the blocking. Not sure if filtered index would help here with performance hit on insert. Then again it depends on what the SP is doing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I did a test when my server was full with a modified version of my sp. The times were significantly lower. So the filtered indexes did their job. I guess if all processes were to work like that the times would have been even lower.(significantly) The problem is that I need to make everything dynamic there so that all the processes will take advantage of this particular code. Basically I know (i tested) that the code would run faster, I do not know what would happen when such a high number of indexes will have to be maintained.

Comment: @t_m no .. I did not, but I checked the plans, indexes used, and everything related to it. And it's ok. I do not think that I can get much more out of it as it is now.